# Do you need to be on windows to import windows related modules?

Tags: python, pycharm

This may be a stupid question but I am struggling to import windows related modules into PyCharm while running on Linux Mint. E.g. PyHook, pywin32. I get no module found. Other modules install fine though. I have tried Python 2 and 3. Do I have to program in windows to import these?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to. These modules need Windows specific APIs that Linux doesn't have. You might be able to work with a Windows Python under Wine, but this is a fragile setup.

Comment: Ah thank you, it's a simple question that could have taken ages to figure out the hard way!